# Setting up Ethernet Connectivity in Android Application

Tags: android, static, ip, ethernet, gateway

While trying to provide Ethernet Connectivity to my Android Device running on Jellybean,
I used ifconfig and route commands to setup Ethernet Connection.
Now I am trying to execute these commands from an Android application, but am not able to set the IP and gateway address.
Is there anyother way of executing these commands?
I used the following code,

```
public void root_command(String cmd)
{
try{
      Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
      DataOutputStream  stream=new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
      stream.writeBytes(cmd);
      stream.writeBytes("exit \n");
      p.waitFor();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
}
catch(InterruptedException e)
{
}
```

}

these are the commands,

```
                 busybox ifconfig eth0 <ip_address> up
                 busybox route add default gw <gateway_address> eth0
```

Comment: what is this "Ethernet Connectivity" ? and the Android device I assume it's not a Phone ? You have a device which has an input of an Ethernet cable ? And you want the device to be to be in your LAN ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am using a custom Android tablet having ethernet port. I am now developing an app that can execute the above busybox commands to connect to the Internet via Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
 Read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String[] returncommand = new String[8];
            returncommand=read_file(filename);
            line1.setText(returncommand[0]);
            line2.setText(returncommand[1]);
            line3.setText(returncommand[2]);

            String[] mycommand = {"ifconfig eth0" + " " + returncommand[0] + " " + "netmask" + " " + returncommand[1] + " ", "netcfg eth0 up",
                    "route add default gw" + " " + returncommand[2] + " " + "dev eth0"};
            if (returncommand[0] != null & returncommand[1] != null & returncommand[2] != null)
                RunasRoot(mycommand);

        }
    });
}

public void RunasRoot(String[] cmds) {
    try {
        java.lang.Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        for (String tmpcmd : cmds) {
            outputStream.writeBytes(tmpcmd + "\n");
        }
        outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```